# image upload with Ajax and without Submit button in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, upload

I'm using Codeigniter. I need to upload **Avatar** image for my site. I need to upload image with `Ajax and Jquery`. But `NO` need Submit button. When I click upload->open it's directly goes to upload via ajax/jquery.

Here after only im going to start my code. If you want sample code, [use this link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

*Note:* (looks & functions) It's should same for all browser.
and I don't want any uploader package.

Thanks...

Comment: share your code, that you have tried?

Comment: I'm going to put my code. This before i used http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html . it's fine. but it's not enough.

Comment: What does 'all browsers' actually mean? IE6? Netscape Navigator? The answer will depend a lot on the browsers you need to support.

Comment: @Jerry don't worry about browser. 1st slove my problem. then we'll speak abt that.